# Flutter Graph FL_Graph Increase Scale of Graph

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have this step counter (all hardcoded for now), that displays weekly steps in a graph using the FL_Graph library. I want to increase the scale of the graph from 1x1 to 100x100, so I can pass in 1000 and it will only go up 10, but on hover will display 1000. Right now, I have to pass in 1.000 and it displays it as 1.000, but I want to be able to pass in 1000. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[![When I click the second dot it displays .9 instead of 900 because I can't change the scale][1]][1]

Here is my code:

**Usage**

```
Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 119, 119, 119),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                width: size.width * .89,
                                child: Column(children: [
                                  Transform.translate(
                                      offset: const Offset(0, 10),
                                      child: const Text('Steps this week',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 30))),
                                  Positioned(
                                      height: 300,
                                      child: AspectRatio(
                                        aspectRatio: 1.50,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: 23,
                                            left: 15,
                                            top: 24,
                                            bottom: 12,
                                          ),
                                          child: LineChart(
                                            mainData(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ))
                                ])),
```

**Support Widgets**

```
  List<Color> gradientColors = [
    Color.fromARGB(255, 47, 255, 0),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 132),
  ];

  bool showAvg = false;

  Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16,
    );
    Widget text;
    switch (value.toInt()) {
      case 1:
        text = const DefaultTextStyle(style: style, child: Text('M'));
        break;
      case 2:
        text = const DefaultTextStyle(style: style, child: Text('T'));
        break;
      case 3:
        text = const DefaultTextStyle(style: style, child: Text('W'));
        break;
      case 4:
        text = const DefaultTextStyle(style: style, child: Text('Th'));
        break;
      case 5:
        text = const DefaultTextStyle(style: style, child: Text('F'));
        break;
      case 6:
        text = const DefaultTextStyle(style: style, child: Text('Sa'));
        break;
      default:
        text = const DefaultTextStyle(style: style, child: Text('Su'));
        break;
    }

    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      child: text,
    );
  }

  Widget leftTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 210, 210, 210),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 15,
    );
    String text;
    switch (value.toInt()) {
      case 1:
        text = '1k';
        break;
      case 4:
        text = '6k';
        break;
      case 7:
        text = '12k';
        break;
      case 10:
        text = '18k';
        break;
      default:
        return Container();
    }

    return Transform.translate(
        offset: const Offset(15, 0),
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: style,
            child: Text(text, style: style, textAlign: TextAlign.left)));
  }

  LineChartData mainData() {
    return LineChartData(
      gridData: FlGridData(
        show: true,
        drawVerticalLine: true,
        horizontalInterval: 1,
        verticalInterval: 1,
        getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return FlLine(
            color: Colors.white10,
            strokeWidth: 1,
          );
        },
        getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) {
          return FlLine(
            color: Colors.white10,
            strokeWidth: 1,
          );
        },
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        show: true,
        rightTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        topTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            reservedSize: 30,
            interval: 1,
            getTitlesWidget: bottomTitleWidgets,
          ),
        ),
        leftTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            interval: 1,
            getTitlesWidget: leftTitleWidgets,
            reservedSize: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      borderData: FlBorderData(
        show: true,
        border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff37434d)),
      ),
      minX: 0,
      maxX: 6,
      minY: 0,
      maxY: 10,
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          spots: [
            FlSpot(0, stepmap['M']! / 1000),
            FlSpot(1, stepmap['T']! / 1000),
            FlSpot(2, stepmap['W']! / 1000),
            FlSpot(3, stepmap['Th']! / 1000),
            FlSpot(4, stepmap['F']! / 1000),
            FlSpot(5, stepmap['S']! / 1000),
            FlSpot(6, stepmap['Su']! / 1000),
          ],
          isCurved: true,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: gradientColors,
          ),
          barWidth: 4,
          isStrokeCapRound: true,
          dotData: FlDotData(
            show: true,
          ),
          belowBarData: BarAreaData(
            show: true,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: gradientColors
                  .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8YIR.png
```

**StepMap (What I want to be displayed is the value of the map)**

```
  var stepmap = {
    'M': 0,
    'T': 900,
    'W': 800,
    'Th': 2680,
    'F': 6870,
    'S': 3210,
    'Su': 1029
  };
```

Thanks!